# convert the CR/LF line terminators in that file to Unix-style LF line terminators?

Tags: unix

Please help. I need to turn this in before 4pm for this Unix class. I have been working on it since 7pm last night. Haven't slept. There are three parts to this assignment. I only need help with the last part. If I can't complete this I fail the class.

Stage 3

In that same directory, write a script asciiFix.sh that takes an arbitrary number of file paths from the command line and carries out the same analysis on each one. If a file is not Windows ASCII, your script should do nothing to it. For each file that is Windows ASCII, your script should print the message

converting *fileName*

and should then convert the CR/LF line terminators in that file to Unix-style LF line terminators.

For example:

```
cp ~cs252/Assignments/ftpAsst/d3.dat wintest.txt
./asciiFix.sh /usr/share/dict/words wintest.txt fileType.sh  
converting wintest.txt
and, after the script has finished, you should be able to determine that wintest.txt is now a     Unix ASCII file.
```

When you believe that you have your script working, run

~cs252/bin/scriptAsst.pl
If all three scripts are working correctly, you will receive your access code.

My Attemps:

```css
#!/bin/sh
for file in "$@"  do
     if file "$file" | grep "ASCII text, with CRLF"; then
     echo "converting $file"
     sed -e s/[\\r\\n]//g "$file"
 fi    
done
```

result:

```
    ./asciiFix.sh: 3: ./asciiFix.sh: Syntax error: "if" unexpected (expecting "do")
    aardvark.cpp /home/cs252/Assignments/scriptAsst/winscrubbed.dat differ: byte 50, line 1

    Failed: incorrect file conversion when running ./asciiFix.sh 'aardvark.cpp' 'bongo.dat'    '     cat.dog.bak
```

Ii have tried taking out if and then. i have tried sed -i 's/^M//g' "$file",also using dos2unix, as well as some other stuff I dont remember. but it always says incorrect conversion with those files.

After adding the ; and switching to dos2unix:

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in "$@";
do
     if file "$file" | grep "ASCII text, with CRLF"; then
     echo "converting $file"
     dos2unix "$file"
 fi    
done
```

the Error that I now get:

```
dos2unix: converting file aardvark.cpp to Unix format ...

Failed when running: ./asciiFix.sh 'aardvark.cpp' 'bongo.dat' 'cat.dog.bak'
```

Comment: 4pm. Which time zone, lol? (Are you still living on a disc?)

Comment: The assignment contains an imprecise term "Windows ASCII".  ASCII is a well-defined character set but not (normally) the one in use on Windows.  What is intended here is probably [code page 1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) which is the default character set on Western Windows installations, but it's by no means the only possible interpretation.  Of course, it seems that they actually only care about the line endings in the file, not about which superset of ASCII it uses.

Comment: you really should do your homework yourself... hint: regular expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `;` before `do`. `do` counts as a new statement. Alternatively you could place the `do` on a new line. In my opinion, the most comfortable way to convert DOS line endings (CRLF) to Unix line endings (LF-only) is dos2unix. If you fix your `;`error, using `dos2unix` instead of `sed` should be straight forward and trivial.

Comment: Adding the ; helped, and I switched to dos2Unix. I am still getting an error however.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all your help.
The code that finally worked was:

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in "$@";
do
    if file "$file" | grep -q "ASCII text, with CRLF"; then
        echo "converting $file"
        dos2unix "$file"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Please mark this (or another) answer as accepted, so that this question no longer shows up as unresolved.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since dos2unix 7.1 you can use dos2unix itself to test for CRLF. This way you are not limited to ASCII.

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in "$@";
do
    if [ -n "$(dos2unix -ic $file)" ]; then
        echo "converting $file"
        dos2unix "$file"
    fi
done
```